# A book featuring experiencing your victim's pain and a surgically-grafted dragon tattoo

Tags: story-identification

I remember a book from when I was younger. The standout aspect was the tattoo that the main character had. It was a dragon, but it wasn't made with ink. It was actually surgically grafted onto him. Also, if I remember correctly, the justice system punished crimes by having the perpetrator experience exactly what his victim felt. A man had shot another in a robbery so a robotic arm fired the same caliber of projectile into him, at the same trajectory and velocity. It was a very stand-out scene for me. I read the book nearly 30 years ago, so any help is appreciated

Comment: The tattoo part sounds somewhat like the Dragonback series by Timothy Zahn. But that came out in 2003. :/ sorry

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like Samuel R. Delaney's Babel 17 (1966).

"it's psychologically important to feel in control of your body, that you can change it, shape it. Going on a six month diet or a successful muscle building program can give quite a sense of satisfaction- So can a new nose, chin, or set of scales and feathers.

...
He returned with a tray full of various fragments. The only recognizable one was the front half of a miniature dragon with jeweled eyes, glittering scales, and opalescent wings: it was less than two inches long.

"When he's connected up to your nervous system, you'll be able to make him whistle, hiss, roar, flap his wings and spit sparks, though it may take a few days to assimilate him into your body picture. Don't be surprised if at first he just burps and looks seasick. Take your shirt off, please."

...
The Officer fingered his shoulder. "It feels odd to have a three inch hole there and your arm still working."

The bit about the justice system doesn't fit, but the questioner seemed less certain of that, so I'd call it probable.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly "The Looking Glass of the Law" (1978) short story by Kevin O'Donnell, Jr.

My notes say "computerised judge plants hallucinations of agonising pain as punishment, appropriate to crime"

Comment: There's also a similar thing going on in one of Heinlein's late novels ("The Number of the Beast" or "Job") where the protagonist visits an alternate North America where the local legal system explicitly operates on the "an eye for an eye" principle. There's a description of cops carefully making sure that a hit-and-run driver receives exactly the injuries that he had inflicted on his victim.